# Ubuntu 22 and Apache protected access

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have a website that was set in 2004 with an ISP running Debian. The ISP just jacked up my yearly fees 3x without warning, I am playing around with a Cloud Server running Ubuntu 22.

I haven't played with Linux for more than 25 years and no experience with Ubuntu and setting up servers.

- Want to set-up an Apache2 Server to run a small hobby website
- The initial webpage (index.html) is a welcome screen and links to sub-pages and it is not protected
- The sub-pages are not protected but when you want to download files, you link to a protected webpage via .htacces and .htpasswd

Without a password, the pages are working as expected, all the links are working fine. I just can't make the passwords work. For now I want to just test the Main page with username/passwords

#### This is my conf file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com

 DirectoryIndex index.html

 DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/

 ServerName mytestsite.com

 ServerAlias www.mytestsite.com

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

#### This is the current .htaccess

```
/var/www/mysite/.htacces

AuthType Basic

AuthName "Restricted Access to SFP1 Files"

AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd

Require valid user

Require user capun1950
```

#### This is the current .htpasswd

```
/var/www/mysite/.htpasswd

capun1950:$*******$************ (encoded value is false)
```

#### So here are my questions

- is the syntax correctly in the .htaccess file? I see some files with a Directory directive

  ```
  <Directory "/www/private">
  ```
- Am I missing other steps, or files?

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So you're asking about Ubuntu Core 22  (ie. the *snap* only flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server)... 22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products don't forget..  *with some different security models used by apps running on them*

Comment: The password file is specified in `.htaccess` as `/etc/apache2/.htpasswd` but your post shows `/var/www/mysite/.htpasswd`. I do not recommend placing `.htpasswd` within the site's directory `/var/www/mysite`. Review this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04). Edit you post after you double-check your OS version.